# What are the advantage of using move in c++

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following function

```
std::pair<Eigen::ArrayXXd, Eigen::VectorXd> f(...){
    ...
    auto a = Eigen::ArrayXXd(N,M);
    auto b = Eigen::VectorXd(M);
    ...
    return {std::move(a), std::move(b)};
}

int main() {
     ...
     const auto &[a_up, b_up] = f(...);
     writeToFile("b_up.txt", b_up);
     ...
}
```

In the Function `f` we allocate and initialize the Eigen Array and Vector `a` and `b`. With the `move`-keyword we still use the same memory that was allocated inside the function `f`. With `const auto & b_up = f(...)` also outside the function `f` the same memory space is used, so we never had to copy anything. Is this correct? But what is the advantage over Pass-by-reference. Does there copying happen?

Comment: Are you compiling without warnings? Because with warnings on, the compiler _should_ already tell you to remove it (being a pessimization). `std::move` returns a reference, which is more awkward than just doing RVO for the compiler, even moreso as you are returning _two_ references there which could in fact be the same object.

Comment: @Damon No, I get the correct result. It is more a theoretical question. Because since I while I often see this `move` statement and I wonder if this is a lot better then pass-by-reference.

Comment: Well yes, of course you get the correct result, you get that anyway. It's just that moving is more of a disadvantage performance-wise than an advantage. Google for "move pessimization" or "copy elision rules" or similar terms. First random hit: https://diego.assencio.com/?index=f57f25fd5a187c70fc7f34fcf5374773

Comment: @Damon The  concerns about move pessimization (I mean using `return move(result);`) do not apply here, because the returned type is different from the type of the moved  objects. Using `move` as shown in the question is OK and desirable.

Comment: @j6t Thank you, can you explain a bit more why it is desirable?

Comment: @Suslik The alternative would be not to use `move`: `return {a, b};`. But that would make copies of `a` and `b` in order to construct the returned `std::pair` object. (Of course, I'm assuming that move-construction of the involved types is far less expensive than copy-construction.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return` statement in `f` function creates `std::pair` witch is not copied further, due to RVO, even if you write:

```cpp
auto ab_pair  = f(...);
```

But still the `a` and `b` have to be moved or copied, but there is a way to construct that pair in place using `std::piecewise_construct` and then return it by reference with RVO:

```cpp
auto f(...){
    std::pair<Eigen::ArrayXXd, Eigen::VectorXd> result{
        std::piecewise_construct,
        std::make_tuple(N,M),
        std::make_tuple(M),
    };

    ...

    return result;
}
```